# ElasticSearch: Using query string for IN queries

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to do something similar to an IN statement in SQL, e.g.

```sql
SELECT * FROM es_index WHERE in_col in ('v1', 'v2', 'v3') AND match_col='v4';
```

I need to do this with a **query string** (this is a must) in ElasticSearch since only this function is exposed for me, so I tried out

```js
// GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(in_col: [v1, v2, v3]) AND (match_col:v4)"    
    }
  }
}
```

But it gave me a parsing error

```
Cannot parse 'in_col: [v1, v2, v3]': Encountered \" \"]\" \"] \"\" at line x, column y.\nWas expecting:\n    \"TO\" ...\n
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN is basically an OR condition so you can do it like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "in_col:(v1 OR v2 OR v3) AND match_col:v4"    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess there really is no other way.

Comment: Yeah, this works, but I'm already aware that this works. I thought perhaps there is an IN function for lucene.

Comment: No there isn't, this is the way to do it... It's just a different syntax, but it works as you expect.